# How to merge two stored procedure data

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have 2 stored procedures, each SP returns 2 data set with same schema.

data are like

```
Stored procedure 1
```

`Table1`

```
ID       Name
1        Apple
2        Sony
3        DELL
```

`Table2`

```
OrderID  CustomerName
101        AB Stores
202        Sony World
301        PC House
```

Stored procedure 2

`Table1`

```
ID       Name
21        HP
32        LG
34        ACCER
```

`Table2`

```
OrderID  CustomerName
1301        X-PC World
2202        Your PC House
3301        Ajant Stores
```

Now I want to merge data like this inside other stored procedure

meargeData1 = SP1.Table1 + SP2.Table1

meargeData2 = SP1.Table2 + SP2.Table2

please suggest me hot I can achieve it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions like [`OPENROWSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) (as in the linked question the @PreetSangha included) don't cope with multiple result sets - they only give you the first result set.

Similarly, using a construct such as [`INSERT ... EXEC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) will cope with multiple result sets from stored procedures, but it will store all of the results in a single table - you won't be able to pull them apart. (There are other issues with `INSERT ... EXEC` that aren't worth going into here also)

About the only way I can see to do this is by writing some procedural code somewhere in a language that isn't TSQL. This could either be in whatever client applications you're building, or a CLR stored procedure. In either case, you'll have to perform the merge manually.

Answer (score 0):

Collect the results of both procedures into a into a temporary table like in question.

[Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)